# JaCoCo missing executable issue

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I have a small Maven application which uses JaCoCo for test coverage report. I keep getting the following error:

> Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file

Here is my POM.xml file. I have removed the Project Element myself.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.mathema.www</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco_sample_app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>jacoco_sample_app</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>report</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>           
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my main class which is under the `src/main/java` structure:

```
public class Punkt {
    private Double x;
    private Double y;

    public Punkt(Double x,Double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Punkt(Punkt zweiterPunkt) {
        this.x = zweiterPunkt.x;
        this.y = zweiterPunkt.y;
    }

    public Double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(Double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(Double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean punkteVergleichen(Punkt zweiterPunkt) {
        return this.getX().equals(zweiterPunkt.getX()) &&  
       this.getY().equals(zweiterPunkt.getY());

    }
    public String toString() {
        return "("+this.x+","+this.y+")";
    }

}
```

And here is class with unit tests which is under the `src/test/java` structure:

```
public class PunktUnitTests {

    @Test
    public void PunkteVergleichen()  throws Exception {
        //a(10.0, 20.0)
        Punkt a = new Punkt(10.0,20.0);

        //b(30.0,40.0)
        Punkt b = new Punkt(30.0,40.0);

        //Der Fall X1!=X2 und Y1!=Y2
        //a(10.0,20.0) und b(30.0,40.0) sind unterschiedlich
        assertFalse(a.punkteVergleichen(b));

        //Der Fall X1 == X2 && Y1 == Y2
        //a(10.0,20.0) und c(10.0,20.0) sind gleich
        Punkt c = new Punkt(a);
        assertTrue(a.punkteVergleichen(a));

        //Der Fall X1 == X2 && Y1 != Y2
        //a(10.0,20.0) und c(10.0,90.0) sind unterschiedlich
        c.setX(10.0);c.setY(90.0);

        assertFalse(a.punkteVergleichen(c));
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What command did you use to start Maven? I cannot reproduce that with `mvn clean package` for example.

Comment: mvn clean install

Comment: Can you show the directory structure you're using for your test? Where are they located? What is under `src/test/java`?

Comment: My tests are located under this structure : src/test/java and then comes the package structure.

Comment: How are your test named? Can you post one of them along with its location?

Comment: I have added the class being tested and the class with JUnit Tests. If you like, u can now run the complete project for yourself.

Comment: @user1107888 Can you please add your `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration ?

Comment: I am using the default config for sure-fire, no changes there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the message may be a bit misleading, the [JaCoCo Maven plugin](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) will emit this warning when no tests have been run. This is your problem here: by default, the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) executes tests that follow a particular naming convention, namely:

- `"**/Test*.java"`;
- `"**/*Test.java"`;
- and `"**/*TestCase.java"`.

But your test is named `PunktUnitTests`, with a trailing "s", and it causes it not to be executed. Thus, what happens is the following: the Surefire Plugin is not running any tests, so the JaCoCo agent is never used, and, as a result, the execution data file is not getting created.

The simple solution here is to rename your test according to the conventions of the Surefire Plugin, namely to `PunktUnitTest`.

Another solution would be to configure the plugin to execute your tests ending with "s":

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that if you want to prevent such errors in the future, you can configure the Surefire Plugin to fail if no tests are run, by setting the [`failIfNoTests`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#failIfNoTests) parameter to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for first of all solving the problem and secondly clarifying the concept. I have marked your answer as accepted. Cheers :)